# What is the datatype of "value" in "set" accessor?

Tags: c#, type-hinting

I'm just wondering what is the datatype of `value` variable in C#'s `set` accessor?

Because I want to implement type-hinting in C#'s set accessor.

For example, I have a setter method:

```
public User
{

    private string username;

    public void setUsername(SingleWord username)
    {
        this.username = username.getValue(); // getValue() method from "SingleWord" class returns "string"
    }

}
```

Now how do I implement this in C#'s accessor syntax?

```
public User
{
    public string Username
    {
        get ;
        set {
            // How do I implement type-hinting here for class "SingleWord"?
            // Is it supposed to be:
            // this.Username = ((SingleWord)value).getValue();    ???
        }
    }

}
```

So that I can call it this way:

```
User newuser = new User() {
    Username = new SingleWord("sam023")
};
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's the source code of `SingleWord`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Guitar32.Exceptions;
using Guitar32.Common;

namespace Guitar32.Validations
{
    public class SingleWord : Validator, IStringDatatype
    {
        public static String expression = "^[\\w\\S]+$";
        public static String message = "Spaces are not allowed";
        private String value;

        public SingleWord(String value, bool throwException = false) {
            this.value = value;
            if (throwException && value != null) {
                if (!this.isValid()) {
                    throw new InvalidSingleWordException();
                }
                //if (this.getValue().Length > 0) {
                //    if (!this.isWithinRange()) {
                //        throw new Guitar32.Exceptions.OutOfRangeLengthException();
                //    }
                //}
            }
        }

        public int getMaxLength() {
            return 99999;
        }

        public int getMinLength() {
            return 1;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }

        public bool isWithinRange() {
            return this.getValue().Length >= this.getMinLength() && this.getValue().Length <= this.getMaxLength();
        }

        public override bool isValid() {
            return this.getValue().Length > 0 ? Regex.IsMatch(this.getValue(), expression) : true;
        }
    }

    public class InvalidSingleWordException : Exception {
        public InvalidSingleWordException() : base("Value didn't comply to Single Word format")
        { }
    }
}
```

I used this class to provide back-end validation by adding `SingleWord` as the datatype required from the setter.

Comment: You can try something like explicit type conversion as found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx

Comment: value is keyword which sets the value of the variable projected via property to the assigned value of same type

Comment: @BabuJames thanks for the explicit type conversion idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `value` is the type of the property, no matter what.

So in your example,

```
public string Username
{
    ...
    set
    {
        value.GetType() // -> string
        ...
    }
}
```

The simple solution for what you're looking for is to just call `.getValue()` on your `SingleWord` instance,

```
User newuser = new User()
{
    Username = new SingleWord("sam023").getValue()
};
```

Or better yet, but I assume this won't work because of code you haven't shown us,

```
User newuser = new User()
{
    Username = "sam023"
};
```

But if that's an absolute no-go, what it sounds like you're looking for is an [implicit operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) on `SingleWord`. If you have the ability to modify the class, you can add an operator that looks like this, and it'll automatically perform the conversion to a `string` such that you should be able to use the syntax you've listed.

```
public static implicit operator string(SingleWord d)
{
    return d.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
Anyway, I added the source code of my `SingleWord` class.
I actually use that class as my back-end validation.